# Appending dynamic variable to a Python dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

I have the following code:

```
headertoken = getauthKEY.json()['auth_token']
print headertoken #i am checking answer and it comes out as I want it
headers = {'token': 'howdoiputtheaboveheadertokenhere??'}
```

I am using the requests module from Python to get the token, and it works fine. But I need to append it to my headers that I later use to call another API with the header token I am grabbing from this first API call.

I cant find anything, its impressive I am stuck with something this simple!

Comment: `headers = {'token': headertoken}`?

Comment: This wont work, I tried it. It will be read as headertoken, and not the value

Comment: You're mistaken (or lacking some key detail).  You have extra quotes somewhere they don't belong, or you're not actually showing us the code you're trying to use.

Comment: Based on the answers and comments you're getting, it is completely unclear what your question is. Consider rephrasing and adding more context.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `headers = {"token": headertoken}` ?

Or are you really asking an XY problem that comes down to editing an existing dictionary? In that case:

`headers["token"] = headertoken`

Comment: First one wont work, as it wont append the value. And second one wont work either, because I need to define the name of the header. So my key:value has to be: token:thedynamicvar

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand the problem correctly, but is it not as simple as:

```
headers = {"token": headertoken}
```

To be clear, if we have:

```
>>> headertoken = "abcdef"
>>> headers = {"token": headertoken}
```

Then, we have:

```
>>> print(headers)
{'token': 'abcdef'}
```

Of course, if you do `headers = {"token": "headertoken"}`, `print(headers)` will return `{'token': 'headertoken'}`.

Comment: This wont work, I tried it. It will be read as headertoken, and not the value

Comment: I updated my answer. If that doesn't work, can you give the output of `print type(headertoken)`?

Comment: This worked! I cant believe I missed such a small detail and did not remove the '' around headertoken.

Comment: No problem, that happened ;)